# how to append the string in key dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to append the number in my javascript key object. I tried with this code

```
arr.push({[`name${num}`]: value})
```

my Output is `[{"name[object Object]":"text"}]`

I will get the `num` dynamically, my expected output

```
[{"name2":"test"}]
```

Comment: Your variable num contains an object, not a number. Try console.log(num) to see the object structure.

Comment: Your code has unbalanced brackets, it shouldn't run at all.

Comment: So you need to post what you actually executed.

Comment: @Marco thanks you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a curly bracket. It should be:

```
arr.push({[`name${num}`]: value}).
```

Also, it appears that the num variable is not a primitive type. Did you assign an object to the num variable by mistake?

Comment: The missing curly bracket was a copying error -- the code wouldn't even run the way he originally posted it.